# EXCEL 2016 ERROR [42601] syntax error at or near "["; No query has been executed with that handle

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerquery

I'm trying to import some data to Excel 2016 from postgres using power query and it shows the message error:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "[";
>   No query has been executed with that handle

But when I use Data>New Consult>Other Sources>ODBC then it imports correctly.
Both Connections use this properties:

> Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=postgres;Data Source=Base_local;Extended Properties="DSN=Base_local;DATABASE=dados_totalip;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;UID=postgres;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;FakeOidIndex=0;ShowOidColumn=0;RowVersioning=0;ShowSystemTables=0;Fetch=100;UnknownSizes=0;MaxVarcharSize=255;MaxLongVarcharSize=8190;Debug=0;CommLog=0;UseDeclareFetch=0;TextAsLongVarchar=1;UnknownsAsLongVarchar=0;BoolsAsChar=1;Parse=0;ExtraSysTablePrefixes=;LFConversion=1;UpdatableCursors=1;TrueIsMinus1=0;BI=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=1;UseServerSidePrepare=1;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;XaOpt=1";Initial Catalog=dados_totalip

How can I avoid this error?

EDIT:
The way that works: on Data ribbon > connection > add existing connection> import to table/pivot table then it imports correctly. Note: this way the option "only connection" is disabled and i don't know why.

The way that doesn't work and i need to work.: on PowerPivot ribbon> management > import external data> from other sources> ODBC > existing connection  (same as the first) > select table > view and filter then Error 42601.

Hope it get clear, if need more details let me know how

Comment: You should describe your setup in more detail. What exactly is the difference in between the case where it works and where it doesn't? Look at the PostgreSQL server log to get the query that throws the syntax error. That might tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

I've Found a way to pass through this error.

First Open an ODBC connection, then import it as "only connection". Ok
Second choose "Recent Connections" and thats it! Just follow the way to Power Query and do you work.

Thanks!